# I get this error when I try to compile my code for CS50 week 4 filter-less

Tags: clang, cs50

I am doing Week 4 Filter-less for CS50, I get an error whne I try to compile my code

When I complie it is see this erorr.

/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start': (.text+0x1b): undefined reference to` main'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [: helpers] Error 1

This is my code
#include "helpers.h"
#include <math.h>

```
 // Convert image to grayscale
 void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
         {
             float r = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
             float g = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
             float b = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
             float grey = round((b + g + r)/3.0);
             image[i][j].rgbtRed = image[i][j].rgbtGreen = image[i][j].rgbtBlue = grey;
          }
     }
     return;
 }

 // Convert image to sepia
  void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < width / 2; j++)
         {
             int w = width - (j + 1);
             RGBTRIPLE tmp = image[i][j];
             image[i][j] = image[i][w];
             image[i][w] = tmp;
         }
     }
     return;
 }

 // Reflect image horizontally
 void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
         {
              int b = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
              int g = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
              int r = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
              int sepiaRed = round((0.393 * r) + (0.769 * g) + (0.189 * b));
             int sepiaGreen = round((0.349 * r) + (0.686 * g) + (0.168 * b));
             int sepiaBlue = round((0.272 * r) + (0.534 * g) + (0.131 * b));

             if (sepiaRed > 255)
             {
                 sepiaRed = 255;
              }
              if (sepiaGreen > 255)
              {
                  sepiaGreen = 255;
              }
             if (sepiaBlue > 255)
             {
                  sepiaBlue = 255;
             }
             image[i][j].rgbtBlue = sepiaBlue;
             image[i][j].rgbtGreen = sepiaGreen;
             image[i][j].rgbtRed = sepiaRed;
         }
     }
     return;
  }

 // Blur image
 void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
 {
     RGBTRIPLE tmp[height][width];
     for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
         {
             tmp[i][j] = image[i][j];
         }
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
     {
          for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
          {
              int totalRed = 0;
              int totalGreen = 0;
              int totalBlue = 0;
              float counter = 0.00;

          for (int x = -1; x < 2; x++)
          {
              for (int y = -1; y < 2; y++)
              {
                  int X = i + x;
                  int Y = j + y;

                  if (X < 0 || Y < 0 || X > (height - 1) || Y > (width - 1))
                 {
                     continue;
                 }

                  totalRed += image[X][Y].rgbtRed;
                  totalGreen += image[X][Y].rgbtGreen;
                  totalBlue += image[X][Y].rgbtBlue;

                  counter++;
                 }
                  tmp[i][j].rgbtRed = round(totalRed / counter);
                  tmp[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(totalGreen / counter);
             tmp[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(totalBlue / counter);
          }
         }

     }


     for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
         {
              image[i][j].rgbtRed = tmp[i][j].rgbtRed;
              image[i][j].rgbtGreen = tmp[i][j].rgbtGreen;
              image[i][j].rgbtBlue = tmp[i][j].rgbtBlue;
         }
      }
      return;
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/62576. And expecting us to help you solve problems with code we cannot see is ridiculous. If you want help with issues with your code, post the code in the form of a [mre], as required by the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Comment: See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), consider a chat with the duck (really), and see [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/3422102)